# Assistance with FOR /F batch parsing data to a text log file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to add devices' MAC Address to the current LogOn batch file as an additional resource for troubleshooting if needed. There is a For /F to get the workstation's IP Address into a varible which a few directories copies the query's data. The command that I am trying to gather which I am having trouble with is the 2nd For /F after the Proceed: section

```css
@Echo Off

MD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\UserLogon\%date:/=%"
CLS
Echo ---------------- >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\UserLogon\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
Echo ---User Logon--- >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\UserLogon\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
Echo ---------------- >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\UserLogon\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
Echo UserName: %username% >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\UserLogon\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
Echo Computer: %computername% >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\UserLogon\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
Echo LogOnServer: %logonserver% >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\UserLogon\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
Echo Date:     %date% >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\UserLogon\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
Echo Time:     %time% >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\UserLogon\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
For /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=[]" %%* In (
   'ping.exe -r 1 %Computername%') Do (Set "IP=%%*" & GoTo:Proceed)

:Proceed
Echo %IP%>>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\UserLogon\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"

For /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%M In (
   "NBTStat -a %Computername% | FindStr "MAC Address"") Do (Set "MAC=%%M" & GoTo:Continue)

:Continue
Echo MAC Address: %MAC%>>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\UserLogon\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"

MD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\CompLogon\%date:/=%"
CLS
Echo ---------------- >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\CompLogon\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"
Echo ---User Logon--- >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\CompLogon\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"
Echo ---------------- >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\CompLogon\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"
Echo UserName: %username% >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\CompLogon\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"
Echo Computer: %computername% >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\CompLogon\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"
Echo LogOnServer: %logonserver% >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\CompLogon\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"
Echo Date:     %date% >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\CompLogon\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"
Echo Time:     %time% >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\CompLogon\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"
Echo %IP%>>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\CompLogon\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"
Echo MAC Address: %MAC%>>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\CompLogon\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"

MD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByUser\%date:/=%"
CLS
Echo ---------------- >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByUser\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
Echo Computer: %computername%>>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByUser\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
Echo UserName: %username%>>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByUser\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
Echo %IP%>>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByUser\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
If Not Exist "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts" GoTo XP
If Exist "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts" GoTo Win7

:Win7
cscript c:\windows\system32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -l  >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByUser\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
cscript c:\windows\system32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -g >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByUser\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"

Echo ---------------- >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByUser\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
GoTo Next

:XP
cscript c:\windows\system32\prnmngr.vbs -l  >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByUser\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
cscript c:\windows\system32\prnmngr.vbs -g  >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByUser\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
Echo ---------------- >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByUser\%date:/=%\%username%.txt"
GoTo Continue

:Next
MD "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByComputer\%date:/=%"
CLS
Echo ---------------- >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByComputer\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"
Echo UserName: %username%>>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByComputer\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt" 
Echo Computer: %computername%>>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByComputer\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"
Echo LogOnServer: %logonserver% >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByComputer\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"
Echo %IP%>>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByComputer\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"
Echo ---------------- >>"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\ByComputer\%date:/=%\%computername%.txt"

Exit
```

I have tried using ipconfig /all | FindStr "Physical Address" or GetMac and feel that NBTStat is best displaying only the active adapter connected to the network. I am not familiar with options: skip, token, or delims. The results displays:"Echo is Off." Any explaination is appreciated as examples on the Internet are mostly querying text files and not sub commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `skip=` command ignores the first (numbertobeskipped) lines of the file or command that is the source of data.

In your case, the command you have programmed will execute the `nbtstat` command with its appropriate arguments and pass the output of that command to `findstr` which filters the resultant report to find the target string. The output from `findstr` is then processed by `for/f` exactly as if it was a file, so the first "hit" on a target string will be skipped (as skip=1) and `tokens=*` means all of the line following will be assigned to `%%M` (but leading spaces will be removed). The value is assigned and the `for` terminated by the `goto`.

There are a few problems with what you have programmed.

First, you need to escape the pipe `|` in the command with a caret `^` which tells `cmd` that the pipe is part of the command to be executed, not a part of the `for`.

Next, the syntax of `findstr` is that the quoted string is a **list** of target strings to find. Your command would find **either** `MAC` or `Address`. To find a string with an embedded space, use `/c:"string with space"`

Next problem  is that the command to be executed **must** be enclosed in *single* quotes (there are options to change this.) Using double quotes will make the value appear to be a *string* to be parsed (and the `skip=1` means "ignore the first (which happens to be the *only*) string"

So, fixing that line to

```
For /f "tokens=*" %%M In (
'NBTStat -a %Computername% ^| FindStr /c:"MAC Address" ' ) Do (Set "MAC=%%M" & GoTo Continue)
```

should resolve the matter. Note however that the value assigned to `%%M` would be the **entire** line (minus leading spaces) so it would be resolved to

```
MAC Address = xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
```

If you want just the xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx part, then you'd need to use

```
For /f "tokens=3delims== " %%M In (
'NBTStat -a %Computername% ^| FindStr /c:"MAC Address" ' ) Do (Set "MAC=%%M" & GoTo Continue)
```

where it's important to note that the `delims` setting (which sets token delimiters) is <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> - the characters between the `delims=` and the closing quote are defined as delimiters, so the string returned would be tokenised to

```
token1:MAC
token2:Address
token3:xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
```

That is, look at the string, process from the beginning, ignore leading delimiters (spaces or `=`), first token is a string to the next delimiter-sequence, then the next token,delimiter-sequence,etc. You need the third group, so `tokens=3`

Comment: Thanks for the detail explaination which helped tremendously understanding the options' functions as well as syntax usage.